# Async await - it is the right Idea to avoid a blocking UI?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I thaught that using await / async is the best Idea to ensure a responsive UI. But I seem to do something wrong, because my Application freezes anyway.

Wht I Try to do:
A Button is launched and should await a long lasting operation.

```
public async Task CmdLoadExcel()
{
    // läd die excel datei
   string[] excelFiles = this.GetExcelFiles();
   ExcelLoader eloader = new ExcelLoader();
   await eloader.StartLoading(excelFiles);
   foreach (DataSet elem in eloader.Tables)
   {
       this.ActivateItem(new ExcelViewModel(elem) { DisplayName = elem.DataSetName });
   }
}
```

The launched Class:

```
public async Task StartLoading(string[] files)
        {
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                Stopwatch swatch = new Stopwatch();
                swatch.Start();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo(file);
                using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(finfo))
                {
                // very long operation
                }
            } // For Each
        } // StartLoading
```

It simply halts at the sleep and I am unsure what I have done wrong.

Comment: Replace that with `await Task.Delay(5000)` I guess

Comment: Please read up on `async` a bit instead of just experimenting. I have [an intro on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) are good (including the [TAP document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx)), and there are several books now that cover it as well.

Comment: @Stephen Cleary :Actually, I have read you blog post beforehand - unfortunately, I did not catch the threading part.
As a side note: While trying to get the TAP document from your blog post, there was an error. Maybe the link is out of date?

Comment: I did change that link a month or two ago. Just double-checked and it's working now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marking methods with async and await doesn't really do anything by itself. You need to await a task:

This would help:

```
public async Task StartLoading(string[] files)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {            
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            Stopwatch swatch = new Stopwatch();
            swatch.Start();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo(file);
            using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(finfo))
            {
            // very long operation
            }
        } // For Each
    };
} // StartLoading
```

Comment: @Erik Schierboom Both of you methods are causing an error along the "After a return statement is no object statement allowd" I am using the german version, so it is a rough translation.

Comment: Are you doing something after that return statement? Or did you implement the snippet as is?

Comment: There are several procedure calls at the "very long operation" part, including a try..catch. The epplus package is used in the using block.

Comment: If you just include the code snippet as is, it should not give you an error. Please try that, if the error goes away, then please post the code in the "very long operation"-part

Comment: @ChristianSauer Sorry for that, I had an error in my code. I just updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yor `StartLoading` method appears to be lacking any `await` statements.  The `async` keyword does not magically make a method able to run asyncronously.  You can `await` a `Task.Delay` as an async-alterative to your `Thread.Sleep`.  For your very long operation, you probably need to spawn a new thread if it is CPU bound.  If it is IO bound, then it is a matter of whether you have access to an Async API that you can use.

See [Three Essential Tips For Asysnc](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Three-Essential-Tips-for-Async/Three-Essential-Tips-For-Async-Introduction) on MSDN Channel 9 for the start of a good introduction.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the link.
Actually, the program is probably both: it reads data and transforms them on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your StartLoading task itself isn't asynchronous. You can fix this using the following code:

```
public Task StartLoading(string[] files)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                Stopwatch swatch = new Stopwatch();
                swatch.Start();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo(file);
                using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(finfo))
                {
                        // very long operation
                }
            } // For Each    
        });
} // StartLoading
```

Then you can use the code as follows:

```
public Task CmdLoadExcel()
{
    // läd die excel datei
   string[] excelFiles = this.GetExcelFiles();
   ExcelLoader eloader = new ExcelLoader();

   var task = eloader.StartLoading(excelFiles);
   return task.ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                foreach (DataSet elem in eloader.Tables)
                {
                    this.ActivateItem(new ExcelViewModel(elem) { DisplayName = elem.DataSetName });
                }
            });
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!
I will look up the ContinueWith Method, I am not sure what it does ;)

Comment: @ChristianSauer Basically what the `ContinueWith` method does is it allows you to "attach" code to a task that is called when the method finishes. [see MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue might be that the line "await eloader.StartLoading(excelFiles);" is actually running on the same (UI) thread. You need to execute it like below. This will cause the method to be run on a ThreadPool thread.

```
await Task.Run(eloader.StartLoading(excelFiles));
```

Comment: I presume you don't want to run the 'foreach (DataSet elem in eloader.Tables)' statement before the StartLoading has completed. Awaiting StartLoading will cause the execution to go back to the method that called CmdLoadExcel in the first place, and execute the foreach only after StartLoading has completed.